# Array returns first element blank in my Rails(3.2.11) multi-select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

When I selected multiple values from select list then array returns the first value empty.

```
= f.select :assignedto, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, 'name', 'name',f.object.assignedto),{}, { :multiple => true}
```

I tried with `{:include_blank => false}` and `{:include_hidden => false}` but this is not working for rails 3.2.11. I have many solutions to handle this empty value in the controller but I want to stop adding empty value in the array.

Comment: It's a long shot but can you please confirm that `name` of the first user is not `nil/empty string` ?

Comment: @SikandarTariq Yeah I confirm that the name of the first user is not nit or empty. If I choose more then 1 name then it also added empty value

Answer (score 0):

Properly because the second arg is `'name'` instead of `'id'`.

Try
`options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, 'id', 'name', f.object.assignedto)`

Comment: Thankyou for your reply!! but it is not working. I tried to change the `'name'` into `'id'`

Comment: May I ask what is the initial value of `f.object.assignedto`?

Comment: Its initial value is first user`s name

Comment: Can the initial value be the user's `id` that you want to select by default? Or it has to be the `name`?

Comment: By default selected value is name not id .